# I want to waterproof from outside, but my neighbors live 2 ft from us, is it possible?

Tags: waterproofing

We live in a 90 year old home that has just begun to leak. The walls have always been somewhat damp, but nothing a dehumidifier couldn't help.  We are now interested in waterproofing from the outside, but our neighbors live 2 feet from us.  Some plumbers say this isn't possible, while others say they are looking into it...still haven't heard! Is it possible, or is it safer to waterproof from the inside?  Also I have heard that waterproofing old homes from the outside could be detrimental to the foundation as it should be a little moist, is this true?

Comment: A plumber?!  I would call waterproofing company in your area and ask them.

Comment: need a lot more information. What kind of walls? Framed, concrete, ???????  If they have been damp for a long time, what caused that????  Where do you suspect the water is coming from?

Comment: what are you waterproofing? Foundations?

Answer (score 2):

you should always stop leaks at the earliest opportunity. whichever way it's getting in that's where you stop it. don't worry about some old tales about keeping foundation a little moist. What do you mean by waterproofing from the outside being difficult because of 2 feet to neighbour? Are you wanting to wrap the wall from the outside? is that where the water is coming in or is it coming in under eaves or behind gutters or leaky roof...or a leaky drainpipe in the soil?
Unfortunatelly when you ask particular trades people about a difficult to locate source of moisture, they typically only say that they can do x y z...and it will cost $$$ but no guarantee it will fix the problem. sometimes it takes years to find the true source of the problem. addressing it is the straight forward part.